# Spring API Cross Domain

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-security

I got a tomcat server using Spring and a React website. I'm trying to fetch data, with postman it's ok but when I'm using my react frontend this is the error I got :

> Access to fetch at
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8080/planningAccouplementWS/acquerirFemelles' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

On the frontend side, I'm calling this code :

```
static acquerirFemelles(femelles) {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("apikey", "sfj4-R5sdhffhs-fnhvSDFYT:DSRrfdj#fhqsm4zxwc-vhglxs15");

    let obj = [];
    femelles.forEach(femelle => {
        obj.push({
            "codePays": femelle.cheptel_pays,
            "numeroNational": femelle.numero_national.substring(2),
            "nom": femelle.bovin_nom
        })
    });
    var raw = JSON.stringify({
        "listeFemelles": obj
    });

    console.log(raw);

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw
    };

    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/planningAccouplementWS/acquerirFemelles", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

And on my server side :
WebConfig.java

```
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH")
            .allowedOrigins("http://locahlost:3000")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowCredentials(true)
            .maxAge(3600);
    }

}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:/security.properties")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${yourapp.http.auth-token-header-name}")
    private String principalRequestHeader;

    @Value("${yourapp.http.auth-token}")
    private String principalRequestValue;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Cors configure");
        APIKeyAuthFilter filter = new APIKeyAuthFilter(principalRequestHeader);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                String principal = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
                if (!principalRequestValue.equals(principal))
                {
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("The API key was not found or not the expected value.");
                }
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                return authentication;
            }
        });
        httpSecurity.
        antMatcher("/**").
        csrf().disable().cors().and().
        sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().addFilter(filter).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() 
    {
        System.out.println("Cors corsConfigurationSource");
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        CorsFilter filter = new CorsFilter(source);
        return source;
    }

}
```

And finaly my GET method

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
    @PostMapping("/acquerirFemelles")
    public DonneesElevages acquerirFemelle(@RequestBody DonneesElevages donneesElevage) throws MetierException {
        System.out.println("Acquerir Femelles");
        DonneesElevages de = new DonneesElevages();
        FemelleMetier femelleMetier = new FemelleMetier();
        CoefficientMetier coefMetier = new CoefficientMetier();

        HashMap<String, ParametreIndex> listeParametreIndex = coefMetier.rechercherParametresIndex();

        de.setListeFemelles(femelleMetier.rechercheFemelles(donneesElevage.getListeFemelles(), listeParametreIndex));

        return de;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have the @CrossOrigin annotation on your mapping method, put this annotation on to your controller class.

if you want to do it the simple way, you can just use @CrossOrigin annotation up on your controller classes.
But anyway, be cautious that this will let through all requests no matter from which url or port they're coming from.

Comment: I moved the @CrossOrigin annotation hover the method but in my current code it's already hover the class. And the problem still the same

Comment: Did you use it without parameters? So that all Request can go through?

Comment: Also you could try to put "*" into your allowedOrigins in the WebConfig Class for testing, to find the problem

Comment: I tried without parameters and allowedOrigins with "*" already too